# Form submits even with validation errors

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

The form submits even when there are validation errors.  How do I disable the submit button when there are validation errors?  Here is the .js file

```
,submitFu:function(){
_.validateFu(_.labels)                          
if(!_.form.has('.'+_.invalidCl).length)
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:_.mailHandlerURL,
        data:{
            name:_.getValFromLabel($('.name',_.form)),
            email:_.getValFromLabel($('.email',_.form)),
            phone:_.getValFromLabel($('.phone',_.form)),
            //fax:_.getValFromLabel($('.fax',_.form)),
            //state:_.getValFromLabel($('.state',_.form)),
            message:_.getValFromLabel($('.message',_.form)),
            owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
            stripHTML:_.stripHTML
        },
        success: function(){
            _.showFu()
        }
    })          
},
showFu:function(){
_.success.slideDown(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        _.success.slideUp()
        _.form.trigger('reset')
    },_.successShow)
})
},
```

And here is the form:

```
    <form id="contact-form" action="contactTq.php" method="post">
                    <div class="success"> Contact form submitted! <strong>We will be in touch soon.</strong></div>
                    <fieldset>
                        <label class="name">
                            <input type="text" name="name" value="Enter Your Name:" >
                            <span class="error">*This is not a valid name.</span>
                            <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                            <span class="clear"></span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="email">
                            <input type="text" name="email" value="Enter Your E-mail:">
                            <span class="error">*This is not a valid email address.</span>
                            <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                            <span class="clear"></span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="phone">
                            <input type="text" name="phone" value="Enter Your Phone (optional):">
                            <span class="error">*This is not a valid phone number.</span>
                            <span class="clear"></span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="message">
                            <textarea name="msg">Enter Your Message:</textarea>
                            <span class="error">*The message is too short.</span>
                            <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                            <span class="clear"></span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="buttons"><strong><a class="button" data-type="reset">Reset<span></span></a></strong><strong><a class="button" data-type="submit" href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('contact-form').submit();">Submit<span></span></a></strong></div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knockout.js does a wonderful job of doing exactly what you're looking for. You can slip your existing javascript into a ViewModel, and then put a data-bind on your button to enable if all fields validate. You can see how to do so here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/enable-binding.html

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are submitting the form as soon as the button is clicked because the onclick handler is written as below:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('contact-form').submit();"
```

Just change the onclick handler to execute the `submitFu` function and that should do the trick.

Comment: thankx plalx.. but now how do I change it such that the form isn't allowed to submit if it is not validated..? thnx for your help

Answer (score 0):

Change the onclick event of your submit button to
    onclick="return submitFu()"

If the validation fails, return false and the form will not submit.  I think you can do the same with the onsubmit event of the form.